# Check if integer is valid bitwise enum value

Tags: vb.net

is there a way to check if an integer is a valid value for an enum even if the value is bitwise?

Example:

```
  Public Enum eFlags As Integer
    None = 0
    First = 1
    Second = 2
    Third = 4
  End Enum

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim x As eFlags = eFlags.Second Or eFlags.Third
    Dim y As Integer = 5

    Dim res = x.GetType.IsEnum AndAlso [Enum].IsDefined(x.GetType, y)
  End Sub
```

This returns false. I want to set the value of a property using reflection where the property is an enum and the value is integer...

Comment: the value that `x` holds is not explicitly defiled in the enum. You can use [`HasFlags`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-5.0) instead.

Comment: I don't think there's a built-in way to validate that a value is within the range of possible flags for a flag enum.  It's fairly trivial to do, though... make a "max value" which is the next highest power of two, and check that anything you get is less than that.  If you have "holes" in the flags, catching those would be more problematic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
<Flags> Public Enum eFlags As Integer
    None = 0
    First = 1
    Second = 2
    Third = 4

    'note: flags added above will have to be Or'ed in All
    All = First Or Second Or Third '<<<<<<<<<
End Enum

 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim x As Integer = 14

        For y As Integer = 6 To 13
            Dim res As eFlags = CType(x And y, eFlags)

            If eFlags.All.HasFlag(res) Then
                Stop
            Else
                Stop
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```